# How to remove a package I compiled and installed manually?

Tags: macos, package-management, compile, source-code

I recently compiled and installed Git on a new install of Mac OS 10.6 but it didn't install the documentation.

I now realize I should've used the precompiled package offered here: http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list

How do I remove all the files that I added to my system using `make install` with the Git source code?

Edit: I've had similar problems in the past with other packages, too. For example, `./configure` with the incorrect `--prefix=` or something. What's the general practice for removing unix packages?

Comment: Have you tried `make uninstall`? Some makefiles support that.

Comment: `make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.` :(

Answer (score 5):

`make uninstall` often works.  If your makefile doesn't support that, then your best bet might be to run `make -n install` (which will list the steps that `make install` does without actually doing them) and manually reverse its steps.

You can also look at different distros' Git packages (such as [Debian's](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/i386/git-core/filelist)) to see what files those packages install.  You might have to adjust the paths a bit for an install from source, but it should give you a pretty good idea of what files need to be deleted.  (Debian, for example, splits Git between [several packages](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=git&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all), so you might need to check the file lists for each.)

Comment: Good answer. It is also worth checking the documentation to see if there is anything like a (semi-)official separate uninstall script or recipe (a common wiki/FAQ entry for well documented OSS projects is "how do I remove it", often linked from any articles on upgrading/moving an install if you can't find it directly) if there is no uninstall target in the makefile, before manually working back from `make -n`'s output.

Comment: Given so much output of `make -n install` for git, it is not applicable to manually reverse the installing steps.